# PostgreSQL full-text index search syntax issues between different versions

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, psql, inverted-index

We had an issue a couple of weeks back where our text-index query wasn't yielding any results. This was the expression:

```
"test_column" @@ websearch_to_tsquery('english', "in_search_argument")
```

We had to update it to:

```
"test_column_idx" @@ websearch_to_tsquery('english', "in_search_argument")
```

..where `test_column_idx` is defined as:

```
"test_column_idx" gin (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, 'test_column'::text))
```

Our server is 14.6 (with psql 12.16).

However, my development environment complains about this:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column p.test_column_idx does not exist
```

If I change it back to use the column (see above; it matched just fine in our development environment even if our production didn't), it works again. Our development environment uses server 14.9 (we closed the gap between versions while debugging) and psql 15.4.

What syntax should I be using to maintain compatibility between environments?

Added (thanks @RichardHuxton):

So, SQLAlchemy creates it as an index in development

```
"test_column_idx" gin (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, 'test_column'::text))
```

The SQLAlchemy definition looks like:

```
sqlalchemy.Index(
    'test_column_idx',

    sqlalchemy.sql.func.to_tsvector(
        sqlalchemy.literal(_TEXT_INDEX_LANGUAGE),
        'test_column'),

    postgresql_using='gin'),
```

When I actually deployed it, I had manually added it to production as a column:

```
test_column_idx      | tsvector          |           |          | generated always as (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, test_column::text)) stored
```

So, can anyone suggest how I might adjust the SQLAlchemy definition to create the column instead?

That said, I'm confused how index semantics can be installed as both a column and an index, and the situations where one or the other would be preferred. I could use some clarification.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you just double-check your production setup? Make sure that you don't have any column called that, possibly on an identically named table in another schema?

Comment: Yes. Good insight. Not out of the woods yet. I've added more detail above.

Comment: You need a `tsvector` to search against, but that can be calculated and part of an index (which is what you probably want) or its own column. Afraid I don't know sqlalchemy (avoid ORMs as much as I can) so can't say what is wrong with your setup. You want the index not the column though.

Comment: Your quoting here is confusing.  You quote `in_search_argument` like it was a column name, but that probably doesn't make sense, it is more likely to be text.  And in one place you quote `test_column` is if it were literal text, where it is clearly should be a column name. And `test_column_idx` seems to be the name of an index in one place, but you can't use a index name in an expression as if it were a column name, which you do in another place

Comment: `in_search_argument` is a SQL function argument. "in_" and "out_" are common prefixes on function/stored procedure arguments, so I figured that would imply as much. In PostgreSQL, double-quoting is used for symbol names, and single-quoting is used for literal values. `"test_column"` refers to a column name, `'english'` refers to the name of a language/dictionary/config, and "in_search_argument" refers to a SQL function parameter. I get it. It's confusing, but they're in the code and I kept them for type-hinting, here.

Comment: @RichardHuxton Given that it doesn't seem to like me specifically referencing the index and yet returned nothing when I referenced the original column, how do I use `@@` against an index? I' also confused what the difference would be between the index and the column with the `generated always` clause on it against the original column.

Comment: To come back to this, how should I define the index such that I can refer to it in the matching query? What's the use of a 'generated always' tsvector column that shadows the text values if an index should be preferred? Academic reasons?

Comment: We perform the query against a tsvector column, not (nor ever) directly against an index. If an index is present, it will be used. Posted as formal answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was simple, but the proper flow is also deceptively simple and what I did subtly deviated.

Somehow we had ended-up with a tsvector column and no index, our search function used this column, and to make matters more confusing, I had inadvertently named this column the intended name of the index (`idx_product_1`). So, when I was looking for bugs and reviewing the definition of the search function, I had missed this the first couple of times.

Since what we had worked exactly as intended (see where the issue was, below), we were even more confused. We finally figured-out that:

1. The vector column is created to auto-populate from the normal data
2. The index is created from the vector column
3. The query is executed against the vector column (not against the index directly, which would not be normal but I was getting my wires crossed; see previous comments/answers)
4. The vector column will transparently invoke the index (like normal) if one is found
5. We *don't* need the index for the right results. We just need it to optimize the search.
6. We *do* need to perform the text queries against the vector column because, even though the text-query against the original column won't fail, we'll get incorrect results when doing so (not usually wrong, but usually incomplete).

Therefore, we did this to autopopulate the tsvector column:

```
ALTER TABLE "products" ADD "style_name_vector" tsvector GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
     to_tsvector('simple', "internal_sku") || ' ' ||
     to_tsvector('english', "human_brand") || ' ' ||
     to_tsvector('simple', "style_id") || ' ' ||
     to_tsvector('english', "style_name") || ' ' ||
     to_tsvector('english', "gender") || ' ' ||
     to_tsvector('simple', shopify_product_id::varchar(255))
) STORED;
```

Because the tsvector column is a space-separated list of word-vector representations, we can simply concatenate a bunch of vectored columns in order to search all of those columns simultaneously. This was an optimization not in the previous design.

Create the index:

```
CREATE INDEX "idx_product_1" ON "products" USING GIN("style_name_vector");
```

Do a search (just for a complete example):

```
analytics=> select internal_sku, style_name from products where style_name_vector @@ websearch_to_tsquery('english', 'trail') limit 5;
 internal_sku |               style_name               
--------------+----------------------------------------
 TN100000926  | Mens Paramount Trail Convertible Pants
 RE000127387  | Trail 40
 PA000010810  | Womens Capilene Cool Trail Shirt
 SA000023516  | S Lab trail Running Shirt
 MA100000254  | Womens Vapor Trail Hoodie
```